# Edit variant of product on cart page | Debut | Shopify

Tags: shopify, dropdown, cart, liquid, variant

Is there a simple way to do this? Like simply in the cart liquid? Looking at the [Shopify API documentation](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api#shopify-ajax-api-reference) here, and it's going completely over my head.

Googling isn't yielding much.

~ Edit:

The most recent thing tried was to add this bit of code to my cart.liquid. Of course it doesn't work. I pulled it from my product-template.liquid.  It's probably a bit of overkill but I wanted to see what it would do. I'm sure the solution is more elegant. My thought was that if it worked at all I could pare it down using a process of elimination. Seems like there should be a simple solution.

```
  <select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}" data-section="{{ section.id }}" class="product-form__variants no-js">
          {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {% if variant.available %}
              <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">
                {{ variant.title }}
              </option>
            {% else %}
              <option disabled="disabled">{{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}</option>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </select>

        {% if section.settings.show_quantity_selector %}
          <div class="product-form__item product-form__item--quantity">
            <label for="Quantity">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
            <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input" pattern="[0-9]*">
          </div>
        {% endif %}

        <div class="product-form__item product-form__item--submit">
          <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart-{{ section.id }}" {% unless current_variant.available %}disabled="disabled"{% endunless %} class="btn product-form__cart-submit{% if product.options.size == 1 and product.variants[0].title == 'Default Title' %} product-form__cart-submit--small{% endif %}">
            <span id="AddToCartText-{{ section.id }}">
              {% unless current_variant.available %}
                {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
              {% else %}
                {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
              {% endunless %}
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

It renders a "greyed" out box that reads sold out.
The product isn't sold out, so I would suppose among a few other reasons (probably) that this code doesn't work is that it's looking in the wrong place for product id and is finding nothing. Why that is, I'm not sure.

[image: sold out]

Comment: And what have you tried on your own?

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the description to reflect what I've tried for the moment. @drip

Comment: Where are you assigning `current_variant`?